# Cron job / connection timed out issue

Tags: php, linux, curl, cron, wget

I am using wget in a cron job command to run a bot like this:

```
/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://www.website.com/bot/update?botkey=wpdalasd12laa
```

But it is not working. I get failure emails which contain this repetitive error:

```
> Resolving www.website.com... 55.55.55.55
> Connecting to www.website.com|55.55.55.55|:80... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection timed out) in headers.
> Retrying.
```

Runtime of bot is more than 15 minutes. So I think because of this, connection become timed out.

Probably, running bot via php makes more sense. But because all system running on a framework, it is not easy to apply. Is there anything that can be done running bot via wget or curl by avoiding connection timed out?

Comment: Why not just create a script that downloads a bot and starts it in a separate thread? Then add this script inside crontabs.

Comment: I couldn't understand probably because I am new at linux :). What do you mean by saying download a bot?

Comment: As you have state *Runtime of bot is more than 15 minutes.*, so I presume that the point of this task is to connect to a server that executes some kind of task (bot), that takes 15minutes to complete (correct if I'm wrong). The idea of my suggestion is to divide a monolithic task to some simpler/smaller ones and run them separately from cron. Cron in this case would be used only as a bootstrap to initiate the chain of tasks.

Comment: I understand it know. I can seperate it of course. But I should add new parts to cron when processing data (work of bot) grows. This is also unwanted situation. I think running it via php will be best way.